# MongoDB: Update many documents with different data in each

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of _id:

```
ordersId = ["5ec42446347f396fc3d86a3d", "5ec422d4347f396fc3d86a3c", "5ecefaf0aead3070fbdab7dd"]
```

And I'm trying to update the documents that match these _ids, but with different data in each of them:

```
    const existentOrders = await Orders.updateMany(
        { _id: { $in: ordersId } },
        {
            $set: {
                status: "Reviewing",
                cashier: req.id,
                rate: dataBasedOnId,
            },
        }
    );
```

I have an array of objects that also have these ids:

```
const ordersRates = [
  {
    _id: "5ec42446347f396fc3d86a3d"
    rate: 2434686948.19
  },
  {
    _id: "5ec422d4347f396fc3d86a3c"
    rate: 2434686948.19
  },
  {
    _id: "5ecefaf0aead3070fbdab7dd",
    rate: 93320.00
  }
]
```

So what I'm trying to do is to update each document with the rate that is in the `ordersRate` variable.

Is it possible to update them using only one operation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `bulk write` which will save network round trip time instead using multiple requests.

You have two variables and form list of `UpdateOne` operations and pass it to bulk write.

[Refer](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)